# Oracle- Trigger Compiliation error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to check the month before inserting to the database. the followingg code was triedbut showing a complationng error as `Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.`

this is the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_july
BEFORE INSERT
ON TBL_EVENT
BEGIN
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM EVN_DATE) FROM TBL_EVENT; 
  IF EXTRACT (month from EVN_DATE) == 7 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20110, 'NOT ALLOWED TO INSERT RECORDS DURING JULY');
  END IF;
    END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_july 
BEFORE INSERT ON TBL_EVENT 
BEGIN   
   IF EXTRACT (month from :new.EVN_DATE) = 7 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20110, 'NOT ALLOWED TO INSERT RECORDS DURING JULY');   
   END IF;
END; /
```

Study the documentation, a section "Accessing Column Values in Row Triggers"
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm
to learn how to access columns of the current row within the trigger body. 
In short: You need to use "correlation names" named NEW and OLD

---

Tip: run `SET DEFINE OFF;` before compiling the trigger to avoid bind variable substitution (variables prepended by a colon `:`).

Answer (score 0):

Use it as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_july
BEFORE INSERT
ON TBL_EVENT
Declare
E_date date;
BEGIN
SELECT EVN_DATE into E_date FROM TBL_EVENT; 
  IF EXTRACT (month from E_date) = 7 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20110, 'NOT ALLOWED TO INSERT RECORDS DURING JULY');
  END IF;
    END;
```

Note: Oracle if clause require `=` only once

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple isues with this code.

First it is a before insert trigger, so the value you want to check is not yet in the table. You can't find it with a select.

Triggers are pl/sql code. Any value you select within a pl/sql procedure you have to 'select aaa INTO bbb from xxx; and bbb must be declared before your BEGIN.

In Oracle the equal comparison operator is a single = (not ==).

Within a trigger you have the special qualifiers :new and :old to reference the column values you are working on.

In update triggers only the :new qualifier is usable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_july
BEFORE INSERT
ON TBL_EVENT
BEGIN 
  IF EXTRACT (month from :new.EVN_DATE) = 7 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20110, 'NOT ALLOWED TO INSERT RECORDS DURING JULY');
  END IF;
END;
```